# Git merge/push changes between remote repositories

Tags: git, github

User forks project `https://github.com/foo/project.git` to `https://github.com/bar/project.git` and starts working on `https://github.com/bar/project.git`.

The changes he made to the forked copy can be pushed without any issues.

1. How does user push changes in `https://github.com/bar/project.git` to `https://github.com/foo/project.git`
2. How does user pull changes from `https://github.com/foo/project.git` to `https://github.com/bar/project.git`

Appreciate if you can provide the exact steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

The process is to use "pull requests".  According to the above doc, go to github.com/bar/project.git, click on "Pull Request" and update the destination to point to github.com/foo/project.git.

After the pull request is sent, the owner can review and automatically merge the pull request on the original repo.